# Is there any way to hide certain snippet of code while compiling in Eclipse 3.7?

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control

I have huge code base and I am having difficulty managing it. There are certain code that are dedicate to certain client. So the thing is I would like to make setting so that when I select some setting then the code for selected would be visible? Wondering if this possible in eclipse for java.
Edit:-
I mean plugins for code management.

Comment: Is all the code in one java project? Or is it spread over many projects (possibly each project dedicated to one client)?

Comment: @rationalSpring yes it is in the same project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change to use multi projects, as you said "There are certain code that are dedicate to certain client" ,it is better to split your code base into multi project if it is really huge.

we have 1 million+ LOC for a product, and uses about 100 java projects to manage them, which helps in many ways. for example, different people own different module and own different projects,   Less conflict for version control ,  different component release strategy....

Comment: how to splitting do you mean that i make multiple projects for each client

Comment: @Kitex, yes, exactly. Have one project with all client-independent code, and then separate projects for each client, with dependencies on the client-independent project.

Comment: @Jeen Brokstra  How is that achieved I am confused

Comment: yes, code for each client should not dependent on each other and they are better be in different project.